# getting invalid response '?' instead of Arabic characters

Tags: python, nginx, flask, character-encoding, python-3.5

I'm setting up a new API backend server using nginx along with Python3.5 & Flask framework. I would like to respond client with Arabic text.

development environment:
  Windows 10,
  Python3.6.2,
  Pycharm IDE

Production:
  Ubuntu 16.04,
  Python3.5,
  nginx

Database: SQL server 2017

Only Reading operation from database.

HTTP Get Response is '?' instead of arabic character.

Use json.dumps with ensure_ascii = False and encoding='utf8'

```
      made_database_stored_procedure_query method returns list of database response


   result = made_database_stored_procedure_query('sp_XXX_name', args)

   json_obj = {'data': result}
   json_response = json.dumps(json_obj, ensure_ascii=False, 
        encoding='utf8')
   response = Response(json_response, 
       content_type="application/json;charset=utf-8")

    if not result:
        return
    else:
        return response
```

1. Http GET Response

a. Development environment response:

```
 {
   "data": [
      {
        "id": "0",
        "no": "أ ع ك 8858",
        "serial": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": "1",
        "no": "ب ح ه 6906",
        "serial": "1"
      }
   ]
 }
```

b. Production response:

```
  {
      "data": [
        {
            "id": "0",
           "serial": "1",
           "no": "? ? ? 8858"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "serial": "1",
             "no": "? ? ? 6906"
        }
     ]
  }
```

Comment: On the ubuntu server, what is the output of the commands `locale` and `locale charmap` if you run them while logged in as the user that runs the web server?

Comment: **locale:** LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: **local charmap:** UTF-8

Comment: Hey @snakecharmerb waiting for your reply. Please help